# normal distribution and confidence interval

Tags: normal-distribution

this is the text of my problem

"One standard test have been used many years in a class. The test can give a max of 100 points. The sum can be considered as normal distributed. $\mu = 85, \sigma = 25$

Make a 95% confidence interval for the sum."

So i'm not sure how i should do this. I've tried to find examples around the web but it looks like there are a lot of ways to do this. I need some help so i can get myself on the right track. At this point i'm stuck

Comment: *There are lots of ways to do this?* Then pick one.

Comment: Well, the problem is that i'm not sure what the problem ask me to do. Should the answer be like: [$\mu - 1.96 * \sigma, \mu + 1.96* \sigma$] ? So i basically just plot the numbers there?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: Is that a correct approach? My conclusion is that since both variables are known, the solution i provided is right.